# How to get value if i refresh the page without use of session scope

Tags: jsp, scope, pagecontext

I have one web page in this i have one variable like state and it set value like state , I want this value if i refresh my page then also i want to get value without using of session ,

I try the page scope but it can not give value if i refresh the page,it will return null.

I set value like this...

```
String name="Hello";  
pageContext.setAttribute("user",name);
```

I get value like this

```
String name1=(String)pageContext.getAttribute("user");
```

I don't want to use session in this.

Comment: Does the variable value come from outside the page (js for example), or is it embedded in the page when initially read by the client?

Comment: In the same page where initially read by the client

Answer (score 0):

IMO, you should go with an option of storing your user values in a Cookie. I mean, storing a user name in a cookie wont occupy much space it would be in Bytes and wont hurt your performance too.

You can refer to following post for how to write and read a cookie in JSF. In addition to this, you can handle the cookie contents the way you want to. Just delete the cookies when the "user" gets into your scope.

[How to use cookies in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557710/how-to-use-cookies-in-jsf)

Comment: I don't want to use cookie

Comment: Hmm. Let me know once you get the solution. If you don't wanna use cookies then "localStorage" provided by Mozilla will also not work in your case.