# JSF: Do something only the first time a component is shown

Tags: jsf

how can i invoke a Function only the first time a component is shown on the page in JSF ? Is there a special Interceptor for this case ?

Comment: Perhaps create session scope bean and store a counter inside it. Another possibility is to use cookies http://stackoverflow.com/a/5557896/947111

Answer (score 0):

You can always have a flag in your backing bean and execute the code (maybe a getter) if the flag hasn't been set. (and set it afterwards)